# How to make the series of questions asked?

Tags: c, function

Here is my code. I want it to ask me questions in a sequence. But whenever I enter my choice and put my name it didn't allow me to ask further. How to deal with that?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int new_acc();

int main(){

    int one=1, two=2, three=3, four=4, five=5, six=6, seven=7, new_account;

    printf("-----WELCOME TO THE MAIN MENU-----\n\n");

    printf("%d. Create new account\n",one);

    printf("Enter you choice: ");
    if (scanf("%d",&one)){
        new_account = new_acc(); // calling a function
    }
    return 0;
}

int new_acc(){
    int id; char name;

    printf("Enter your name: ");
    scanf("%c\n",&name);

    printf("Enter your ID card number: ");
    scanf("%d\n",&id);    

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your name to input must be single-character because you are reading only single character as name.

Comment: No it is not working. Although I typed single character.

Comment: What do you mean by not working? You never use any of the input so how do you know?

Comment: `int one=1` hmm... why? What do you expect from this code?

Comment: "it didn't allow me to ask further." okay - so what did happen?

Comment: yoou need loop? Thats what you want?

Answer (score 0):

If you typed Enter after typing nubmer for the MAIN MENU, the newline character remains in the buffer.
Then, is is read as the name via `%c`.
After that, if you typed, for example, alphabet as name, it will prevent it from reading the number `id`.
To avoid this, you can put a space before `%c` to have it skip the newline character.
Also you won't be have to skip after reading name and id, so you should remove `\n` in `scanf()` after `%c` and `%d` for them.

```
int new_acc(){
    int id; char name;

    printf("Enter your name: ");
    scanf(" %c",&name); /* add space and remove \n */

    printf("Enter your ID card number: ");
    scanf("%d",&id);    /* remove \n */

    return 0;
}
```

By the way, the above code will allow only one alphabet as name.
To support multi-character name (without space character), you should use an array of `char` and `%s` with length specified.

```
int new_acc(){
    int id; char name[1024];

    printf("Enter your name: ");
    scanf(" %1023s",name); /* don't use & here, and size limit is buffer size - 1 (-1 for terminating null character) */

    printf("Enter your ID card number: ");
    scanf("%d",&id);    

    return 0;
}
```

If you want to support name with space characters, you can use `%[\n]` (read until newline character) instead of `%s`.

```
int new_acc(){
    int id; char name[1024];

    printf("Enter your name: ");
    scanf(" %1023[^\n]",name);

    printf("Enter your ID card number: ");
    scanf("%d",&id);    

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It is not allowing me give my id number. Whenever I give my name, it stops and then it just shows me **Enter your ID card number** but I am unable to enter there.

Comment: @RedMailers All of above code works fine in my environment: it stop after printing `Enter your ID card number:` and accept my input. Please make sure that you compiled new code and running that.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you want to use an object oriented programming paradigm in this. To so do, you should define an "object" with `struct` and save the new account with that:

```c
#define MAX 50

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Account {
        int id;
        char name[MAX];
};

struct Account new_acc();

int main(){

        int choice;
        struct Account new_account;

        printf("-----WELCOME TO THE MAIN MENU-----\n\n");
        printf("1. Create new account\n");
        printf("Enter you choice: ");
        scanf("%d",&choice);
        switch(choice) {
                case 1:
                        new_account = new_acc();
                        break;
                default:
                        printf("Not a valid option\n");
                        return 1;
        }

        return 0;
}

struct Account new_acc(){

        char name[MAX];
        int id;
        struct Account new;

        printf("Enter your name: ");
        scanf("%c\n",name);

        printf("Enter your ID card number: ");
        scanf("%d\n",&id);    

        strcpy(new.name, name);
        new.id = id;

        return new;
}
```

Pay attention because this code is very vulnerable to buffer overflows. Plus, I edited your check for the option in `main` because `scanf` returns 1 if reads whatever value successfully.

Comment: It is not giving me the option to enter id number.

Answer (score -2):

***Use This Code i have modfified a little bit***

```
int new_acc(){
    int id; char name[10];

    printf("Enter your name: ");
    scanf("%s",name);

    printf("Enter your ID card number: ");
    scanf("%d",&id);    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @MikeCAT This will resolve the problem , Also one thing more you cannot use `\n` in scanf function coz , this will require extra `Return` Character